# How to use aggregate function in lucene query string

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using **apache lucene** for indexing and searching in my application. Everything is working fine and now i've to integrate reporting and for that i need aggregate values. I've been stuck and couldn't find a way to use aggregate function in **lucene search string** like we can use them in **HQL** very easily!

Any hints or way around to use aggregate function in lucene search string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike HQL (and SQL), Lucene query syntax does not let you retrieve aggregates. However, you might be interested in a somewhat similar feature called [faceting](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateSearch34FacetingPerfAndMore) which lets you retrieve category counts for your query .

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField in the schema)

> defaultSearchField to search within different aggregate fields

If you want aggregation in query then combine your data using the data-import schema ,put it in a field and use that field in the defaultSearchField

Comment: I think the question was just about Lucene, Solr wasn't mentioned.

Comment: You are talking about searching in different fields whereas the question is about aggregates on a single field.